# Why are my verification codes not working when I ssh into my ubuntu server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, security, remote-access

I'm trying to setup Google multifactor authentication up on my Ubuntu Server 20.04 machine so that when I ssh into the machine, it will require an ssh key and verification code from the google authentication program.

So far, I have installed google authenticator, ran the command `google-authenticator` and ran through the setup process, including putting the configuration code generated into my authentication app that will generate my verification codes.

I have added/changed the lines in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` to:

```
#@include common-auth
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

and have added/changed the lines in ```/etc/ssh/sshd_config''' to:

```
LoginGraceTime 20
PermitRootLogin no
MaxAuthTries 3
PasswordAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
DebianBanner no

ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
```

I don't think its my verification code generator because when I login locally, it asks for a verification code and takes it no problem. Only getting the problem when I ssh into the machine, which I am doing via PuTTY.

```
login as: [REDACTED]
Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-20220414"
Further authentication required
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
| Verification code:
| Verification code:
End of keyboard-interactive prompts from server
Access denied
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
| Verification code:
```

Thanks!